# Eclipse slow to print keyboard input

Tags: nvidia, graphics, eclipse

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.1 and Eclipse Luna with Oracle Java 8.

When I edit a file, Eclipse prints very slowly. There is a noticeable delay between when I type a word and when that word appears on the screen. Everything else in eclipse seems to work normally though. Overall, it runs faster than Eclipse on my Windows 7 partition. When I type something that's not in a file such as naming a new project, it types normally. I've tried reinstalling Eclipse, editing the `eclipse.ini` file and changing settings but nothing seems to work.

Comment: How much processor/RAM usage do you have when you're experiencing this lag? Like open system monitor and then type some in Eclipse, does RAM and processor usage go to max?

Comment: I have 8 GB of RAM and a 2.2 GHz i7 processor with 8 logical processors. Eclipse uses about 0.6 GB of memory and 5% CPU. With everything else I saw 1.7 GB of memory and 9% CPU used by the entire system.

Comment: have you tried different versions of Eclipse, because it sounds like a weird bug to me...

Comment: I've tried Eclipse Juno with the same results.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out it was a graphics card driver issue. I am using the GF119M [NVS 4200M]. I installed and switched to the NVIDIA legacy binary driver version 304.117 and now everything works flawlessly.